# How to get applied cart price rule in magento add to cart observer checkout_cart_product_add_after?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

How to get applied cart price rule in magento add to cart observer ?

Comment: Which observer event are you using.?

Comment: @NagarajJuro i am using checkout_cart_product_add_after observer

Answer (score 0):

Try to getting the appliedRuleIds by calling the $quote from your $quoteItem

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProcessAppliedRules" name="Vendor_Module::process_applied_rules"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**ProcessAppliedRules.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProcessAppliedRules implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $quoteItem \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $quoteItem->getQuote();

        $appliedRuleIds = $quote->getAppliedRuleIds();

        // Do some crazy stuff here

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the OP has asked in Magento 1 the login is similar as @Tuyen has posted the only thing I would like to add is you get the applied rule ids for each item using

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$appliedRuleIdsOfItems = $quoteItem->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

and if you need for full quote use

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getQuote();
$appliedRuleIds = $quote->getAppliedRuleIds();
```